# Accessing the memory heap in python

Tags: python, memory

Is there a way to access the memory heap in Python? I'm interested in being able to access **all** of the objects allocated in memory of the running instance.

Comment: If I am not wrong and I am not misunderstanding the question, you can do ```globals()```

Comment: @Sujay: That only shows you the stuff visible at global scope in the current module. Adding `locals()` would also let you look at the locals in a given function scope, but even so, you wouldn't see closure/class/instance scopes, nor the variables allocated in other local scopes, or in the globals of other modules.

Comment: Point is, "the heap" is the common store for every dynamically allocated object in the entire program (in CPython, the C stack itself stores almost nothing that's interesting to an observer; the Python-level call stack itself is heap allocated as well), it's not just the handful of things directly visible in LEGB scope at any given point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get *direct* access, but [the `gc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) should do *most* of what you want. A simple [`gc.get_objects()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects) call will return all the objects tracked by the collector. This isn't *everything* since the CPython garbage collector is only concerned with potential reference cycles (so built-in types that can't refer to other objects, e.g. `int`, `float`, `str`, etc.) won't appear in the resulting `list`, but they'll all be referenced by *something* in that `list` (if they weren't, their reference count would be zero and they'd have been disposed of).

Aside from that, you might get some more targeted use out of the `inspect` module, especially [stack frame inspection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack), using [the `traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) for "easy formatting" or manually digging into the semi-documented frame objects themselves, either of which would allow you to narrow the scope down to a particular active scope on the stack frame.

For the closest to the heap solution, you could use [the `tracemalloc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) to trace and record allocations as they happen, or [the `pdb` debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to do live introspection from the outside (possibly [adding `breakpoint()` calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) to your code to make it stop automatically when you reach that point to let you look around).